# Websphere Studio 5.1 Starting issue

Tags: linux, websphere, wsad5.1

I have an old legacy application and its generating the ear file.The application have many other modules.Now we need to build this using Websphere Studio 5.1.

I am using Websphere Studio 5.1 on mint OS. I have already installed the WSAD software . But, while starting this its throwing the below error. The application has installed on `/opt/IBM/WebSphereStudio/ApplicationDeveloper/v5.1.1` path.

Attaching the screenshot.
[image]

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: This is ancient software :-) running on unsupported OS, so your chances are quite weak. I'd suggest to either try to find some old Win XP system/image and try there, or try to use latest Eclipse with WebSphere Developer Tools. You should be able to build ear, but it doesnt support WAS 5.1 integration.

Comment: Thanks @Gas  for your suggestion.  I will try with windows xp. Any suggested WebSphere Developer tool ?

Comment: Either use latest RAD (Rational Application Developer, product that replaced WSAD), or use Eclipse with WebSphere Developer Tools (WDT). WDT can be downloaded via Marketplace or from [wasdev.net](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#filter/sortby=relevance;q=developer%20tools)